# Hamburger Menu not opening when clicked

Tags: html, css

my hamburger menu doesn't open when I click it. It seems like I've added the appropriate code but when I click the menu, it doesn't open and show the navigation items:

Here is my code below:

HTML

```
  <nav class="nav" id="home">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#about-me" class="nav-link">ABOUT ME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">PROJECTS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">SKILLS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="mailto:me@derrickogole.com" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
/* Navigation */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--clr-secondary);
  display: block;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  padding: 12px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Styles */

.toggle-button {
  display: none; /* Hide hamburger menu icon by default */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary);
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

Media Query

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-links {
    display: none; /* Hide regular navigation links */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Add a transition effect */
  }

  .toggle-button {
    display: block; /* Show hamburger menu icon */
  }

  /* Style the hamburger menu icon */

  .toggle-button .bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--clr-secondary);
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
}

/* Add styles for the navigation menu when it's open */

.nav.open {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #fff; /* You can change the background color */
}

.nav.open .navbar-links {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.nav.open .toggle-button .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.nav.open .toggle-button .bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav.open .toggle-button .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".toggle-button");
  const navbarLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar-links");

  menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  });
});
```

What is the issue and how can I rectify it in the simplest way - enabling the menu to show when clicked and show the nav items?

Thank you.

Comment: You are adding the `open` class to `.navbar-links`, but all the selectors in your CSS are using `.nav.open`.

Comment: I don't see the toggle-button class in your HTML.

Comment: @Geshode the toggle-button class is in the second line of the HTML he posted :)

Answer (score 0):

when the screen size gets smaller you are making `navbar-links` display none . Even though you change its styles you won't be able to see it. I recommend to create a different element for new menu that will be opened and show it when you click the toggle button.